# Generate a Fire Register report

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am stuck figuring out a working SQL Query for the fallowing:
I need to generate a Fire Register report (how many people are still inside the building) based on an Access database that records login/logout events along with some metadata.
The Access DB looks like this:

```
+----+---------------------+---------+---------+------+
| id | date                | action  | success | user |
+----+---------------------+---------+---------+------+
|  1 | 2009-04-28 02:00:00 |   login |       1 | Nick |
|  2 | 2009-04-28 03:00:00 |  logout |       1 | Nick |
|  3 | 2009-04-28 04:00:00 |   login |       1 | Nick |
|  4 | 2009-04-28 04:00:00 |  logout |       1 | Nick |
|  5 | 2009-04-28 04:00:00 |   login |       1 | Nick |
|  6 | 2009-04-28 07:00:00 |   login |       1 | John |
|  7 | 2009-04-28 07:30:00 |   login |       1 | Sue  |
|  8 | 2009-04-28 08:00:00 |  logout |       1 | John |
+----+---------------------+---------+---------+------+
```

During the day there can be multiple login/logout actions.
When administrator runs the report, it's only limited for current day and needs to list all users where the last known action for this user is `login` and success=1, meaning that this person is currently in the building.

On the data above, **Nick** and **Sue** must be pointed out as still being inside the building.

Comment: If they have a successful login followed by a failed login, should they still be assumed to be inside the building? It seems like they should, but the wording of your question isn't 100% clear on that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to the problem:

```
SELECT
     T1.user
FROM
     Some_Table T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Some_Table T2 ON
     T2.user = T1.user AND
     T2.success = 1 AND
     T2.date > T1.date
WHERE
     T1.success = 1 AND
     T1.action = 'login' AND
     T2.id IS NULL
```

This assumes that you only care about successful actions. Also, if a user has two actions on the same EXACT date AND time then it might not act as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**sorry typo in the original

```
SELECT     f.[User], la.MostRecent, f.[action]
FROM         
(
   SELECT 
       MAX(ID) AS MaXID, 
       MAX(Date) MostRecent, 
       success, 
       [USER] 
   FROM          
       Fire
   WHERE
       Success = 1
   GROUP BY 
       success, [USER] 
) AS la
JOIN Fire f
  ON la.MaxID = f.ID
WHERE     ([action] = 'login')
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work in SQL, but you'd have to try it with Access.

```
select *
from events e1
where action = login
      and success = 1
      and date = (select max(date) from events e2 where e1.user = e2.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes the ID's are always incremented by a positive number and are unique.

```
SELECT LogTable.* 
FROM LogTable 
INNER JOIN (Select User, Max(ID) AS LastID 
                    FROM LogTable 
                   GROUP BY LogTable.User
                  ) as LastLog
ON LogTable.User = LastLog.User 
           AND LogTable.ID = LastLog.LastID 
WHERE LogTable.success = 1 AND LogTable.action = 'login';
```

Based on assumption, you don't have to worry about a datetime not being unique.

Hope people are not in the habit of holding the door open for others who don't log in.